# How can I prevent "Log in to post comments" from displaying for anonymous users?

Tags: 8, theming, comments

How do I remove the "Log in to post comments" from the bottom of my content in **Drupal 8** while keeping old comments visible to all and allowing existing registered users to still comment? Basically, I don't want anonymous users to find my login page, ever. *These means no CSS hide or Javascript solutions (bots will still follow the link).*

### So, if comments exist on a node:

I want **anonymous users** to:

1. See the comments as usual
2. NOT see any sort of "add comment" link
3. NOT see any sort of "login/register" link either

I want **authenticated users** to:

1. See the comments as usual
2. See "add/reply" comment links as usual

### If comments DO NOT exist on a node:

I want **anonymous users** to:

1. See NOTHING at the bottom of the node

I want **authenticated users** to:

1. See "add comment" link as usual

Comment: Take a look at this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256543/drupal-how-to-remove-login-or-comment-link-from-webform-pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using [hook_preprocess_HOOK](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.7.x)
The following hooks should be placed in `YOURTHEME.theme` file:

1. Remove comment links from node for Anonymous user:

```
    /**
     * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
     */
    function YOURTHEME_preprocess_links__node(&$variables) {
      if (\Drupal::currentUser()->isAnonymous()) {
        unset($variables['links']['comment-forbidden']);
      }
    }
```

2. Remove links from the comments for Anonymous user:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_links__comment(&$variables) {
  if (\Drupal::currentUser()->isAnonymous()) {
    unset($variables['links']['comment-forbidden']);
  }
}
```

Comment: This did the trick. A few clarifications though in case a newbie like me comes across this post (correct me if I am wrong). First, this code should be placed in your theme's `MYTHEME.theme` file. Second, both functions should be named with your theme's name as the first bit: `function MYTHEME_preprocess_link__node(&$variables) {`

Comment: Yes you are right , i will update my answer.